# React Native Web - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I have tried what was mentioned in previous answers but unable to resolve the error:

> SyntaxError:
> node_modules\react-native-gifted-chat\lib\GiftedChat.js:
> Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
> (337:27):

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];
  const plugins = ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"];

  /** this is just for minimal working purposes,
   * for testing larger applications it is
   * advisable to cache the transpiled modules in
   * node_modules/.bin/.cache/@babel/register* */
  api.cache(false);

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5"
  }
```

I completely don't have any clue what is wrong here. The preset is installed, the plugin is installed but yet nothing works and I get same error.

Comment: did you find solution to this? I am facing same error